# Sencha command - not a valid sdk directory, please cd into a valid directory

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-command

I'm having a problem with sencha command.  I've cd'd into the path containing the SDK and then pointed to the path of my app but I get the above error.  Is this a beta bug or am I missing something?  Not sure what else to try....

My command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3>sencha app create MyApp C:\Development\MyNewApp
```

Comment: I  m also in sencha directory still i get message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the SDK folder not the SDK Tools folder to execute sencha command

Comment: Thanks, I wish this was made a little more clear in the documentation.

Comment: What is sdk folder by the way ? I m pulling my hair since yesterday but no help so far.. Im using Sencha Cmd v5.0.0.106 and installed Ruby as well.

Comment: @agpt I have the same question. Did you ever figure out specifically which folder they mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the newest version of Sencha Touch, then you shouldn't use the [Sencha SDK Tools](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?196001-quot-Not-a-recognized-Sencha-SDK-or-application-folder-quot-on-OSX-w-2.0.0-Beta-2-2.0.1-rc&p=908627&viewfull=1#post908627). Instead, download and use [Sencha Cmd](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) (it's a different program with the same name; confusing, yes).

Otherwise, [here's a thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?196001-quot-Not-a-recognized-Sencha-SDK-or-application-folder-quot-on-OSX-w-2.0.0-Beta-2-2.0.1-rc) which discusses this problem. There are a number of solutions presented, one of which is downloading Sencha Touch and creating a `.senchasdk` file within it.